# Last frame of the animation remains on screen (SKTextureAtlas, SpriteKit)

Tags: animation, ios7, sprite-kit

just starting with SpriteKit. Probable because I'm a beginner and I'm missing something very basic, but I'm having problems with this part of my code.

I'm creating a frame by frame explosion animation. I remove the original node (a ball) and in its place I launch this explosionParent method (since is way bigger in size than the original object). Inside I create a SKSpriteNode, and then run the animation over it. After doing that, I check if the animation is finished, and if that's the case I erase the explosionParent node.

The explosion appears in place and runs smoothly, but the last frame of the animation remains on screen (and the node itself). What I'm doing wrong? I guess I'm mixing concepts, but I thought it would be a good experience to share it here. Thanks in advance!

```
-(void) explosionParent:(float)positionX and:(float)positionY {

SKSpriteNode *explosionParent = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Explosion 1"];

explosionParent.name = @"explosionParent";
explosionParent.position = CGPointMake(positionX,positionY);

[self addChild:explosionParent]; // Creating child for the explosion


// Starting animation

SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"RedExplosion"];

SKTexture *explosion1 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-1-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion2 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-2-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion3 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-3-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion4 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-4-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion5 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-5-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion6 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-6-Red.png"];
SKTexture *explosion7 = [atlas textureNamed: @"explosion-7-Red.png"];

NSArray *atlasTextures = @[explosion1,explosion2,explosion3,explosion4,explosion5,explosion6,explosion7];

SKAction *explosionAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:atlasTextures timePerFrame:1.0f/30.0f];


[explosionParent runAction:explosionAnimation] ;  // launching the animation itself


// Killing the explosion node if the action has finished

if (![explosionParent hasActions])   
{
    [explosionParent removeFromParent];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that at `if (![explosionParent hasActions])`, it hasn't finished its actions.  Instead what you should consider doing is chaining some action together, one that does the animation, and on that removes the node from its parent.  You do this using `+ (SKAction *)sequence:(NSArray *)actions`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @InkGolem! My problem was I didn't know I can call `removeFromParent` as an SKAction: `SKAction *removeExplosion = [SKAction removeFromParent];`. You gave me the clue, thanks a lot!